# Futuristic water tower—seemingly simple shape, but how tackle a clean topology?

Tags: modeling

I’m trying to model this—looks fun, right?

[image]

So I’m having issues (perhaps as you’d expect) where the two pipes seamlessly flow into the main hull of the thing—but I got close.

[image]

[image]

I took two cylinders, connected them at the top with a semi-circle “bridge” you see in the center, and then used edge loops to connect it to the body.

It’s *almost* fine, but the topology is a little lumpy and I can’t seem to smooth it out. I’ve tried manually adjusting the vertices.

[image]

It’s especially noticeable as I up the subsurface.

Can anyone help me either fix this or, better yet, help me see a more “correct” way of going about this type of shape?

Thank you.

John

Comment: Could you show your unsubdivided mesh?

Comment: The topology is perfectly fine. Perhaps the resolution / number of edge loops you've started with is too high and doesn't smooth well when using subsurf due to minor misplacement of vertices.

Answer (score 4):

### Use simple shapes and pump up the subsurf subdivision

I would suggest to model your object with simple shapes (e.g. cubes for the pillars, an octagon for the top) then add the subsurf modifier and start tweaking the geometry with the modifier activated.

[image]
[image]

Let the subsurf modifier do the work for you. Use the minimum amount of vertices in order to easily control the shape and let the smoothing flow.

Comment: Thank you for the incredible answer and detailed graphic. Excellently explained.

Answer (score -2):

To be honest, I think all can agree that topology is certainly one of those more difficult areas of modelling. It really just takes practice. My advice for you would be, if you don't like how the way the pipes are connecting, I'd recommend deleting that part and trying it again with a more simple bust before detailing it.